# How to declare an interface above an angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with a method that receives values from a form.
I would like to describe the form data with an interface.

However, at runtime (ng serve), the compiler tells me that the interface is unknown. (`Public property 'friendshipFormModel' of exported class has or is using private name 'IFriendshipFormModel'.`)

How can I declare the interfaces properly ? If possible, I would avoid to create a separate file only for this interface, as it belongs to the component.

The file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { FriendshipModel } from '../models/friendship.model';

interface IDatePickerDateModel {
    day: string;
    month: string;
    year: string;
    formatted: string;
    momentObj: moment.Moment;
}

interface IFriendshipFormModel {
    name: string;
    meetingDate?: IDatePickerDateModel;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-friendship',
    templateUrl: './create-friendship.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-friendship.component.css']
})

export class CreateFriendshipComponent {
    @Output() friendshipCreated = new EventEmitter<FriendshipModel>();
    friendshipFormModel: IFriendshipFormModel;

    constructor() {
        this.friendshipFormModel = {
            name: '',
            meetingDate: null
        };
    }

    createFriendship() {
        const friendshipCreation: FriendshipModel = this.frienshipFactory(this.friendshipFormModel);
        this.friendshipCreated.emit(friendshipCreation);
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, just export interfaces as well

```
export interface IDatePickerDateModel {
    day: string;
    month: string;
    year: string;
    formatted: string;
    momentObj: moment.Moment;
}

export interface IFriendshipFormModel {
    name: string;
    meetingDate?: IDatePickerDateModel;
}
```

Comment: I read several examples like this one http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html where "export" is not needed. Do you know why it is needed now ?

Comment: @VivienAdnot because you are importing `{FriendshipModel}`