# Property 'xxx' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I run into a strange behavior in my angular app today.

```
ERROR in src/main(A,B): error TS2339: Property 'XXX' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

The error occured at the following line of code

```
xxx.subscribe(data => {
    this.var = data.XXX
});
```

So basically i subscribe to an observable and map the data from the observable to an global var. My angular App works as intended, so this error seems to have no effect on the app itself, but I still can't figure out whats wrong here. Below is the console log of `data`:

```
console.log(data)
//{"XXX": "test"}
```

Comment: what if you use  `data['XXX']` instead ? type `{}` does not hold `XXX` attribute, that's why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property '\_body' does not exist on type 'Response'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574305/property-body-does-not-exist-on-type-response)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript complains that you do not have the property inside the data, you can either use any or create an inteface with that property,

```
xxx.subscribe((data:any) => {...}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, what is best practise for this case?

Comment: use an inteface for this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550356/how-to-declare-an-interface-above-an-angular-component

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for reply, voted up. On the other hand, the example on the link is not clear. Could you please add an example to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You have instantiated data as just an object example : `data = {}`.
As object doesn't have `XXX` property it gives this error.
So solution will be `data: {XXX: string, YYY: number ....} = {}`

Else you can access XXX with `data['XXX']` which is the easiest option

Comment: `data['XXX']`should be the answer here. There is no need to interface, model, or specific type. There is absolutely no benefit to use such things for a simple object. Maybe rename `data` to a more specific data type if needed.

Comment: Yes you can achieve the required behavior in that way. But as a best practice better to use Interface kind of things. Else you will rarely get the real benefits of Typescript.

Comment: As best practise, do not return a data object type with one attribute in first place. returns the attribute directly.